# Unset all variables set by the script

Tags: shell, sh

I use variables in my script and run the script in the following way `. ./test.sh`. And as it should be, after the script finishes, all the set variables remain in the shell; I know that at the end of the script one can add `unset variable variable2`. But what if there are a lot of variables, is there a way/command to unset all set variables in the script at once at the end?

Comment: Put it a subshell with parens, as in `(. ./test.sh)`, if you _need_ to source it for some reason, but in general, sourcing the script (running it with `. scriptname`) is something you only do when you _want_ it to be able to change variables / working directory / etc.

Comment: You probably shouldn't view `. ./test.sh` as "running" the script.  Instead, you should view it as anomalous behavior to be avoided.  Unless you have a concrete need to source the script (and you understand what that means and what the script will do), you probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: If your shell supports `local`, you could take advantage of that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to run it with `.`? Normally one does that in order to have variable assignments persist afterward.

If you run the script with just `./test.sh` then it'll run as a child process with a separate environment from the parent shell. Variable assignments in the child will not affect the parent, and they'll be lost when the child exits.